# Are the online servers for Super Smash Bros. Brawl still running?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

Does anyone know if Nintendo still has their Smash Bros. Brawl online server still up and running? At this moment our internet is too slow to wirelessly connect the Wii to the internet so we'll have to buy a cable, but I don't want to buy a cable if their servers aren't running still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

The online services for the Nintendo DS and Wii, collectively Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection, were terminated on May 20, 2014 for all games that used them, including Super Smash Bros. Brawl. The menu option will still show up in the game, but attempting to access online play will only result in a notice stating that Nintendo WFC was terminated.